# React Native Scrollable Screen with Expanding FlatList

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-hooks, components

So I need to display a FlatList that loads items from an object that users will add/delete from in an editing scenario, but the FlatList itself needs to be non-scrollable since the entire screen is within a ScrollView, and said screen must move with the FlatList to display more. I have posted before with this specific issue, but nobody seemed to have the answer, so I've decided to provide some demo screenshots of what is necessary.

Users will edit an object for the FlatList, and upon being saved, said object will be inserted into the array in which the FlatList uses to display the data.

[image]

[image]

What I've attempted: Disabling scroll for the FlatList and embe
dding within a ScrollView; this technique works for about 2 items, and begins to lag the entire device upon the addition of more.

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: The FlatList is in itself a ScrollView that selectively renders, so why are you needing to nest it inside a scroll view?

Comment: There are multiple other components on the screen, so I need the screen itself to be scrollable so you can access other functions on the screen, and from what I've seen, the FlatList just adds its own ScrollView within its component, but I need the scroll to be effective for the entire screen?

Comment: I see. So the issue you're having is the child FlatList scroll event isn't bubbling up to the parent ScrollView scroll event?

Comment: With other components on your screen, push them to [ListHeaderComponent](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listheadercomponent) or [ListFooterComponent](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listfootercomponent) and remove ScrollView. And you can catch event from FlatList.